# parallelize external Makefile

Tags: makefile, multiple-makefiles

I've this Makefile

```
framework:
    @$(MAKE) -C $(HIGGSBASESELECTOR) 
    @$(MAKE) -C $(MATRIX4)
    @$(MAKE) -C $(SUBSELECTOR)
    @$(MAKE) -C $(MCSUBSELECTOR)
    @$(MAKE) -C $(MATRIXSUBSELECTOR)
    @$(MAKE) -C $(CHECKSUBSELECTOR)
    ...
```

if I run

```
 make -j framework
```

it uses only one process. What is the best (and fast) way to refactor this Makfile to parallize the compilation?

Answer (score 0):

Your rule executes the `$(MAKE)` commands *in sequence*, so it's not surprising that you see only one process at a time.

A quick and dirty approach (if nothing's waiting for the results of these calls) is

```
framework:
    @$(MAKE) -C $(HIGGSBASESELECTOR) &
    @$(MAKE) -C $(MATRIX4) &
    @$(MAKE) -C $(SUBSELECTOR) &
    @$(MAKE) -C $(MCSUBSELECTOR) &
    @$(MAKE) -C $(MATRIXSUBSELECTOR) &
    @$(MAKE) -C $(CHECKSUBSELECTOR) &
```

If that makes your blood run cold (and it should) you can do it this way:

```
framework: $(HIGGSBASESELECTOR) $(MATRIX4) $(SUBSELECTOR) ...
    do things after the calls

.PHONY: $(HIGGSBASESELECTOR) $(MATRIX4) $(SUBSELECTOR) ...
$(HIGGSBASESELECTOR) $(MATRIX4) $(SUBSELECTOR) ...:
    @$(MAKE) -C $@
```

Comment: I get: `Makefile:88: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.` on the `.PHONY` line

Comment: I assumed `HIGGSBASESELECTOR`, `MATRIX4` and so on were simple paths. What are they? (Also, I assume you know that by `...` I mean the rest of the target directories, `MCSUBSELECTOR` and so on.)

Comment: Can you give an example of a path that produces the error? Also, what version of Make are you using?